# after update ubuntu 13.04 my pc doesn't show the dock bar won't show

Tags: dock

after update Ubuntu 13.04 which is freshly installed, not showing dock bar and upper bar which is really annoying. i reinstall Ubuntu 3rd time ,but every time the problem happens. i don't know whether it's a bug or not, just showing an internal error occurred. please some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then enter:

```
unity --reset-icons &disown
```